# How to redirect one domain page to different domain page in IIS

Tags: wordpress, redirect, iis, http-redirect

I need to redirect testdomain2.com/contact-us to testdomain1.com/contact-sales

How should I add redirection in IIS.

Website built in WordPress.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module Any search engine can take you there.

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of way you can do.
In your function.php write this code.

```
if(is_page('contact-us')){
ob_start();
$url = 'testdomain1.com/contact-sales';
header('Location: '.$url);
ob_end_flush();
die();
}
```

This should redirect to your page.